# Find maximum and minimum of $f(x,y) = x^2 y^2 - 2x - 2y$ in $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 5$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Find maximum and minimum of $f(x,y) = x^2 y^2 - 2x - 2y$ in $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 5$.

So first we need to check inside the domain, I got only one point $A(1,1)$ where $f(1,1) = -3$. and after further checking it is a saddle point.

Now we want to check on the edges, we have 3 edges: $(1) x=y, 0\leq x\leq y \leq 5$ and $(2) y=5, 0 \leq x \leq 5$ and $(3) x=0, 0\leq y \leq 5$.

So I started with each of them, using Lagrange. I started with the first and got:

$l(x,y,\lambda) = x^2y^2 - 2x - 2y + \lambda (x-y)$.

$l_x(x,y) = 2xy^2 - 2 + \lambda = 0$

$l_y(x,y) = 2x^2y - 2 - \lambda = 0 $

$x-y = 0 \rightarrow x=y$.

But then what to do ? I always get $x,y = \sqrt[3]{1+ 0.5\lambda}$, which gets me nowhere. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Well, we have $f(x,y)=x^2y^2-2x-2y$ considered on the following green area:

[image]

So $f_x=2xy^2-2,~~f_y=2x^2y-2$ and solving $f_x=f_y=0$ gives us the critical point $x=y=1$ which is on the border of the area. Now think about the border:
 $$y=5,~~ 0\le x\le 5 \;\;\;\; x=0,~~0\le y\le 5 \;\;\;\; y=x,~~ 0\le x\le 5$$

If $y=5,~~ 0\le x\le 5$, so $$f(x,y)\to f(x)=25x^2-2x-10$$
 and this easy for you to find the critical points which are maybe the best candidates on this border.

If $x=0,~~0\le y\le 5$, so $$f(x,y)\to f(y)=-2y$$ there is a similar way of finding such points on this border.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful graphics with your answer +1

Answer (score 0):

I just ploted your function and wonder whether there exist max or min at all. It does.

[image]

Comment: According to wolfram there are maximum and minimum.
max = $(5,5)$.
min = $(\frac{1}{25}, 5$

Comment: the image above is by Mathematica, so wonder how that fits Wolfram {Plot3D[x^2 y^2 \[Minus] 2 x \[Minus] 2 y  , {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]}?

Comment: Since your function is symmetric ($f(a,b) = f(b,a)$), if $(1/25,5)$ is a minimum, then so is $(5,1/25)$. And, @al-Hwarizmi, the domain is compact, so a maximum and a minimum will be achieved.

Comment: @Eric thanks. Sure it does. Got tired. Updated to avoid fault.